# Designing a web platform with modules using the EF 4.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, design-patterns, content-management-system, software-design

I am trying to build a web platform (king of a CMS) using the EF 4.3 with migrations. So I want to factorize all my work from other projects like e-store, newsletter, blog etc; into separate ClassLibrary projects containing the models(maybe build some NuGet packages later). And I was hoping I could integrate them into my custom mvc3 template and then use some advanced scaffolding for my controllers and views.

So first I have an MVC3 custom template that has a ClassLibrary project containing my authentication model (some repositories and some custom providers with two Entity Framework objects: User and Role using "BaseDataContext").
And second I have another ClassLibrary project named Blog that contains the model for my blog (all the EF POCO's, some repositories and the "BlogDataContext") 
I also use IoC.

The first problem I encountered was CircularDependecy, I need a reference from my blog to my template and one from my template back to my blog if I want my Blog.Author to inherit from my Template.User and my User POCO to contain a reference to my Author. 
I know that the authentication and blog model are on the same "level" and should be in the same class library but keeping in mind the fact that many more libraries should be allowed to be added later(like for example a "newsletter" library), I can't factor out the entities into one single lib.
The second problem I'm thinking of is using multiple DataContexts but that's another subject.

So in conclusion my question is not very specific. It's more of a arhitectural design question. 
Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? Or is it safe to try and find a walkaround to the CircularDependency problem? 
If not how should I design the "CMS" or how should I make it simple to reuse my work.
(The migrations feature seemed interesting, if for example you have a working e-store and the client requests adding a blog)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi, it is not true; -the same "level" and should be in the same class library- you can use different class library for your entity models if we talk about EF 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into decoupling your whole design, make all logical units (single sign-on, cms, e-comm, reporting etc.) independent of each other and figure out how to communicate between them with the minimum amount of data possible. For example, you can pass the GUID of an authenticated user down to the CMS instead of the whole User object.
Once you figure that out, using [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) and [WF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd980559) you can orchestrate said communications, create workflows etc. The biggest advantage you will get is your platform will be pluggable and scalable, and you can add or remove components depending on your needs or add and remove resources depending on your load.